# Redirecting user to a particular page after login based on role with Razor and ASP.NET Identity Core

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I've scaffolded the Identity pages and I'm trying to update Login.cshtml.cs to redirect the user to a particular page upon successful login.

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
    if(User.IsInRole("Business User"))
    {
        return Redirect("~/BusinessDashboard");
    }
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

I've also tried changing the 5th line to:

```
if(User.HasClaim("role", "Business User"))
```

I know that once this particular user is logged in, it definitely has the role claim of "Business User" because I'm printing the claims out to check them (I've added role as a claim in my startup file by configuring IdentityServer). However, when I put break points on the code above and check User, it doesn't look as though any claims are actually being assigned at this point. Perhaps this is the issue, but if so I'm not sure how to get around it?

Comment: Where do you call that code? In page handler? In middleware? Show more code.

Comment: `PasswordSignInAsync()` has nothing to do with Identityserver. That is from ASP.Net Identity Core, so you would better to configure the claims in Identity DB.

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere else that the user isn't really defined at this point of the ASP.NET Identity workflow so I needed to use an instance of UserManager to get the user based on the username they put into the login input field and then I was able to use the user info I gained to get the roles that could then determine the redirect.

The code below is my updated version of the OnPostAsync method that's included in the Login.cshtml.cs file you get when you scaffold the Identity pages.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

                    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Username);
                    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                    if (roles.Contains("Business User"))
                    {
                        return Redirect("~/BusinessDashboard");
                    }
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).